# Sorting MapReduce results on MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have my MapReduce working correctly to group my results by date. All works well, however I'd like to have the results to be returned from Most Recent to Oldest based on 'created' value.

```
   findTimelineByQuery: function (query, fields, options, callback) {

        var obj = {};

        obj.map = function() {
            emit(Date.UTC(this.created.getFullYear(), this.created.getMonth(), this.created.getDate()), {
                created:this.created,
                title:this.title,
                type: this.type,
                id: this._id,
                owner: this.owner,
                value: this.value
            });
        };

        obj.reduce = function(previous, current) {
            var array = [];
            var res = {items:array};

            current.forEach(function (v) {
                res.items.push(v);
            });
            return res;
        };

        obj.verbose = true;
        obj.query = query;

        _Items.mapReduce(obj, function(error, model, stats) {
            callback(model);
        });


    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at using `aggregate` instead of map-reduce?  Should be simpler and faster.

Comment: I did, but wasn't able to get it working.  How would you set it up? I kept on getting an error. Wish i remembered what it was, since i overwrote it to pursue MapReduce.  I will give it another shot later on.

Comment: Use aggregation framework - your MR isn't doing anything that AF won't do 10x faster...   Do you remember what error you were getting?